# Adyen MarketPay supported countries?

Tags: adyen

According to this doc: https://docs.adyen.com/developers/marketpay/marketpay-overview

Supported countries (12)

MarketPay is currently available for the following countries: Austria, Belgium, Finland, France, Germany, Ireland, Italy, the Netherlands, Portugal, Spain, the United Kingdom (including Isle of Man & Jersey), and the United States.

According to this:  https://www.adyen.com/our-solution/online-payments/marketplaces

Payout 25+ countries

Which is correct and where can I see the list?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems to be a specific support question of adyen and has nothing to do with software development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference here is what MarketPay supports vs the functionality of paying-out.

MarketPay includes functionality like KYC/Customer verification, funds management, as well as payout. This set of functionality is currently available in the 12 countries mentioned in the [MarketPay documentation overview](https://docs.adyen.com/developers/marketpay/marketpay-overview).

For the payout to 25+ countries, this is referencing the functionality of paying out to a bank account or card, independent of the MarketPay solution. This is represented in the docs under the [third party payouts documentation](https://docs.adyen.com/developers/features/third-party-payouts)